# sorting list #sort

Tags: sorting

I wanted to sort 'Country' list by name, then 'China' must always be on top of the drop down list...

Here is my code..

```
<option value="">Country...</option>
<t t-foreach="all_country.sorted(key=lambda x:x.name, reverse=False)" t-as="x">
<option t-att-value="x.id" t-att-selected="int(x.id) == int(((country_id or -1) if country_id else -1))">
<t t-esc="x.name"/>
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your sort key to return a `tuple` with `False` if you find "China", then `False` if you find "Japan", then the actual value.

So if name is not "China" or "Japan", all is `True` and you have natural sorting order, but for those 2, you get `False,True` and `True,False` and natural sorting order of the tuple makes them come first:

change your key argument as follows:

```
key=lambda x:(x.name!="China",x.name!="Japan",x.name)
```

note that you don't need `reverse=False`. This is default.

Answer (score -1):

Just code them hard before you enter the loop and then skip if they come up